# Possible to get a value together with a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Below code works, but I would like to my `query()` at the end to only return `0` or `1` based on

```
return (statusCode === 301 && httpsGet.includes('google')) ? 1 : 0
```

One could probably introduce a global, but it seams wrong.

## Question

How can I get access to `res.statusCode` in the `try` statement?

```
const https = require('https');
    
function httpsGet(opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.get(opts, (res) => {
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', (data) => {
        body += data.toString();
      });

      console.log(res.statusCode);

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(body);
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      reject(e);
    });
  });
}

async function query(options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.timeout = options.timeout || 0;

  const opt = {
    hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
  };

  opt.agent = new https.Agent(opt);

  try {
    // here I would like to check the status code and search in httpsGet return value
    return await httpsGet(opt);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

(async function () {
  const s = await query({ timeout: 1000 });
  console.log('String: ' + s);
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that gets returned is just whatever you pass to the resolve function.

So, if you want the status code, you can just add it to the object you return.

```js
function httpsGet(opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.get(opts, (res) => {
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', (data) => {
        body += data.toString();
      });

      console.log(res.statusCode);

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({
          body,
          statusCode: res.statusCode, // Here we add status code
        });
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      reject(e);
    });
  });
}

async function query(options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.timeout = options.timeout || 0;

  const opt = {
    hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
  };

  opt.agent = new https.Agent(opt);

  try {

    // Unpack return value 
    const { body, statusCode } = await httpsGet(opt);
 
    // Use values
    return (statusCode === 301 && body.includes('google')) ? 1 : 0

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

(async function () {
  const s = await query({ timeout: 1000 });
  console.log('String: ' + s);
})();
```

If you're unfamiliar with destructuring, these two are the same:

```js
  // Unpack return value 
  const { body, statusCode } = await httpsGet(opt);

  // Use values
  return (statusCode === 301 && body.includes('google')) ? 1 : 0
```

Or

```js
  const result = await httpsGet(opt);

  // Use values
  return (result.statusCode === 301 && result.body.includes('google')) ? 1 : 0
```